# backbone router add route as function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js and I have a router. this is my routes property of the router:

```
routes: {
    "pagea": "pageafunc",
    "pageb": "pagebfunc",
    "pagec": "pagecfunc",
}
```

is it possible to add a route that looks like this:

```
"mypath/*subroute": function(subroute) {
    //do somethong  
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the `routes` object can only have string values.

If you want to pass your own callback, you need to set up the route programatically. For instance, in your router's initialize function, you can do this:

```
this.route('mypath/*subroute', 'mypath_subroute', function(){
  // Route callback stuff.
});
```

That said, this can get very unreadable quickly, and it means that you have to scan through your initialize functions to know all of the routes you have defined, so storing all of the routes in the `routes` object is much cleaner. Or at least keep the route function body on the Router itself and keep the route paths in a separate section for readability.

Comment: Thanks! I need this for creating routes dynamically so in the first place it is not that readable like the routes property.

Comment: Because I use this to dynamically create routes, how can I get a different name for each route??..

Comment: You should be able to just append an incrementing id to the name or something. The name is mostly used if you want to bind extra events to the router.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect, or possibly just outdated. In either case, per the official [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes):

> The routes hash maps URLs... to functions on your router *(**or just direct function definitions, if you prefer**)*

Wahoo! That means you should be able to do something like:

```
var
Router= Backbone.router.extend({
  routes:{
    "path/to/:view": function(view){ console.log(view); }
    }
  });
```

It's a handy shorthand if, for example, you'll want to extend modify the `{routes}` object before initial instantiation or somesuch. However, it's worth noting that using an anonymous callback will disable namespaced events from triggering for that route. (See [@loganfsmyth's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/13401882/backbone-router-add-route-as-function/45443497#comment-18311102) above.) Still, this probably isn't the worst trade-off, depending on your use-case.